# How to bake a texture from shader nodes?

Tags: texturing, materials, texture-baking

The other one that I looked at is outdated, So I need to open up a new question, Anyways, I made a texture from shader nodes, And I want to convert it into a texture so I can use it on other things, (Basically an image I think) And I can't find a way to do it, I tried tutorials but it only gives me a blacked out square.

(Also just a quick question, Can ignore if wanted, What's the different between material and textures?)

Comment: The material is what you're going to display on the surface of your object. A texture may be part of your material, like a procedural texture (which is made by Blender, like for example a Noise Texture) or an image texture (i.e. bitmap texture that you import, like for example a wood texture photo). As for baking, you have a lot of tutos, like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYvgFWEiNp8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;TR

The baking of materials and textures are mostly the same with the exception that specular / meticallic values are mostly static in the end and act like fake tints in your baked texture.

## How to bake properly

- Have 2 or more UVs.

  - 1 for texturing, 1 for baking.

## Setup #1

Have an extra Image Texture node + UV node to indicate which texture you wish to bake to. Likewise have the extra UV node be set to the UV that you wish to be used in the baking process, otherwise Blender defaults to the UV that you have selected in your <kbd>Properties Editor -> Object Data Properties</kbd> (mesh tab).

[image]

#### No specified UV node for baking - defaults to selected UV

[image]

## Setup #2

Having your material's roughness and/or metallic is also known to cause black areas if their values are set to a value *other* then **0.0** or **1.0**.

Answer (score 2):

### To bake to an image:

First, make sure your model is UV unwrapped.

Next, set up your material the way you want it. (A *material* is your entire shader setup, nodes, etc. while a *texture* is just an image that you use somewhere in that setup. Material = shader, texture = image.)

Add an Image Texture node. Don't connect it to anything, and make sure it's selected.

Click the *New* button to make a new texture. This is where your bake will end up, so make sure it's the size you want.

Head to the render settings. Switch to the Cycles render engine and scroll down to the Bake section.

Choose the Bake Type that you want. (*Normal*, *Diffuse*, etc.)

If you're trying to just bake the base color, choose *Diffuse* and uncheck *Direct* and *Indirect.*

Then click Bake! It bakes to the image in the selected image texture node. It may take a minute or two.

**Please note that the target image will be totally overwritten, so don't accidentally use an important image.**