# How would you go about retopologizing hard surface models that have a lot of detail?

Tags: modifiers, topology, retopology

So, I made this robotic hand that has a lot of bevels and some booleans. I'm not really sure how i should go about retopologizing all of the details, since I'm only really familiar with retopologizing smoother surfaces like humanoid bodiens. So I was wonder, weather I should make shapes, that simply don't have the bevels, or something completely different? For refference, here's my mode[image]

I mean, it doesn't look that high poly, but when I go into edit mode:
[image]

It has nearly 140k tris, and from what I see, it looks like most of it is being caused by slices as such:
[image]

as well as some of the bevels, as seen in the last image. So, do I just simply have to retopologize it without the bevels and slices, or is there a different way, or well, at least a more correct one.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Whats your goal with retopologizing?  Do you want to make it more suitable for bending or non-rigid animation? Reduce poly count? Something else?

Comment: @gandalf3 I wanted to reduce the tri count, so it's not too much and I can export it to a game engine afterwards. From what I've heard, it seems like a lot of tris for a model that'll be imported into a game. These hand objects in particular won't be deformed, since I'll be parenting them to bones, so it'll only move along the bones, so I'm not sure weather the tri count matters that much in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

140k indeed sounds fairly hefty for a single hand. Since its not deforming, you don't need to care about having triangles or uneven geometry too much so, here are some tools which may be suitable:

- [Decimate modifer](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html#index-0) (and [Decimate Geometry](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/cleanup.html#decimate-geometry) in edit mode)
- [Dissolve edit mode tools](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/delete.html#dissolve)

How much you decimate is of course tradeoff of detail for speed, which is typically made based on your performance needs, your engine's optimization features, your artstyle, and how much it'll be seen (i.e. is this a player character's hand which will be on screen all the time vs an npc or something). There's not really any hard and fast rule, but for example, the small surface greebles and details may be better off removed entirely and instead baked to a normal or displacement map. Here is the documentation for [texture baking in cycles](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/baking.html); the setup can be a bit fiddly if you aren't used to it, [this question might help](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/267692/599).

Comment: Thank you very much! So I got rid of the small details, as highlighted in the last photo of the post, so I made a low poly, that doesn't have such details and kept the high poly, and then baked it as any other humanoid model.